# Show that a set is dense

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

We want to show that the set $S\subset \mathbb{R}$ defined in the following way is dense: $S=\{x: \exists c>0 \text{ such that}\ |x-j/2^k| \geq c/2^k, \ \forall j\in\mathbb{Z},\forall k\in \mathbb{N}_0 \}$.

I tried to use the definition of a dense set, so for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ the ball $B(x,\varepsilon) \cap S\neq \emptyset$ for every $\varepsilon >0$, but did not get anywhere.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but is $c$ a positive real number or a nonzero natural?

Comment: We have $c$ be a positive real, I edited the question.